# How to upgrade the software called Everything published by Void Tools?

Tags: updates, everything

I'm running [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com) by Void Tools - I'd like to update it to a newer version but there's no built in updater, I'm expected to install a new version from the site.

Do I need to uninstall the old version before installing the new one?

Comment: If "This question body does not meet our quality standards" don't simply add this to the question! Instead, rephrase your question to make it more clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Do you have a specific suggestion to make it clearer?

Comment: To start with, you don't describe what this "Everything" is, and your question reads as if you are trying to upgrade everything (=all things)

Comment: @YisroelTech - "Everything" is obviously software.  The author's question is do they have to uninstall Everything in order to update Everything. Everything desktop search utility.  Explaining what Everything isn't need in this case.

Comment: I've rephrased the title to make it more clear this is about a specific software product.

Comment: @Ramhound It's obviously not so obvious, given the system's issue with it (the system's comment he then added to the question) and John's answer.

Comment: What's "directly updated"?

Comment: Go for package manager like Chocolatey and you won't have to worry about how to upgrade things. Not that you have to worry normally either.

Comment: @Destroy666 - [Everything](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/Everything) can be installed with Chocolatey but I am not sure that answers the author's specific question about transferring any settings that might be configured within Everything.

Comment: In other news....I could have sworn I retracted my close vote on this question.

Comment: @Ramhound well, it's not an answer. Most of the software will be handled correctly by Choco's user scripts to preserve configs. Most installers themselves also do it, especiall when software is popular and Everything is. A better question here would be direct "Can I lose config if I upgrade Everything?" or anything alike. "lacks focus" close reason would be much more fitting, but there was no point voting for that with 4 votes already on "lacks clarity", although the questions are pretty clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the new installation, and nothing indicated that it was aware of the old one. Since a service is involved and the doc mentions multiple instances, I opted for the safer option to uninstall the old version first (which is usually the default process, and I don't want old files to be kept, errors due to files being locked, duplicate service installation, appearing twice in the installed apps, etc.).

And the "worst" has happened. I lost my bookmarks, which were the only important thing that I needed. The doc implied that configuration won't be cleaned unless a clean is specifically executed with Everything. Maybe between versions bookmark storage has changed (registry to bookmarks.csv?). To be safe, back up the bookmarks by exporting them beforehand--now, they seem to be kept in a file. If configuration is important, then also save Everything.ini.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using multiple versions of Everything for many years.

My experience is that the configuration is kept when upgrading,
with no problem, and I never uninstalled it.

Uninstalling Everything will likely erase all your settings,
which is not your aim.